# Is it possible to specify handle_unknown = 'ignore' for certain columns and 'error' for others inside OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe with all categorical columns which i am encoding using a `oneHotEncoder` from `sklearn.preprocessing`. My code is as below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


steps = [('OneHotEncoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown ='ignore')) ,('LReg', LinearRegression())]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
```

As seen inside the `OneHotEncoder` the handle_unknown parameter takes either `error` or `ignore`. I want to know if there is a way to selectively ignore unknown categories for certain columns whereas give error for the other columns?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','USA','IND','UK','UK','UK'],
                   'Fruits':['Apple','Strawberry','Mango','Berries','Banana','Grape'],
                   'Flower':   ['Rose','Lily','Orchid','Petunia','Lotus','Dandelion'],
                   'Result':[1,2,3,4,5,6,]})

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

steps = [('OneHotEncoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown ='ignore')) ,('LReg', LinearRegression())]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df[["Country","Flower","Fruits"]]
Y = df["Result"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.3, random_state=30, shuffle =True)

print("X_train.shape:", X_train.shape)
print("y_train.shape:", y_train.shape)
print("X_test.shape:", X_test.shape)
print("y_test.shape:", y_test.shape)

pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

#Mean Squared Error:
MSE = mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)

print("MSE", MSE)

#Root Mean Squared Error:
from math import sqrt

RMSE = sqrt(MSE)
print("RMSE", RMSE)

#R-squared score:
R2_score = r2_score(y_test,y_pred)

print("R2_score", R2_score)
```

In this case for all the columns that is `Country`, `Fruits` and `Flowers` if there is a new value which comes the model would still be able to predict an output.

I want to know if there is a way to ignore unknown categories for `Fruits` and `Flowers` but however raise an error for unknown value in `Country` column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [`ColumnTransformer()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) would help you to solve the problem. You can specify the list of 
columns for which you want to apply `OneHotEncoder`with `ignore` for `handle_unknown` and similarly for `error`.

Convert your pipeline to the following using `ColumnTransformer`

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer([("ohe_ignore", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown ='ignore'), 
                              ["Flower", "Fruits"]),
                        ("ohe_raise_error",  OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown ='error'),
                               ["Country"])])

steps = [('OneHotEncoder', ct),
         ('LReg', LinearRegression())]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
```

Now, when we want to predict

```
>>> pipeline.predict(pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['UK'], 'Fruits': ['Apple'], 'Flower': ['Rose']}))

array([2.83333333])

>>> pipeline.predict(pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['UK'], 'Fruits': ['chk'], 'Flower': ['Rose']}))

array([3.66666667])


>>> pipeline.predict(pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['chk'], 'Fruits': ['Apple'], 'Flower': ['Rose']}))

> ValueError: Found unknown categories ['chk'] in column 0 during
> transform
```

**Note: `ColumnTransformer` is available from version `0.20`.**

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea this was directly possible. The syntax is a mouthful but definitely worth going with something that ships by default with the API.

Comment: Brilliant answer

Answer (score 1):

From v0.20 onwards, you can use the [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) API. However, for older versions, you can easily roll out your own implementation of a preprocessor that handles columns selectively.

[Here's a simple prototype I've implemented which extends `OneHotEncoder`.](https://gist.github.com/Coldsp33d/30d0ff66a7164b371816e52b6f6e00bc) You will need to specify a list of columns to raise an error on to the `raise_error_cols` argument. Any column not specified to this argument is implicitly handled as "ignored".

**Sample Run**

```
# Setup data
X_train

  Country     Flower  Fruits
2     IND     Orchid   Mango
0     USA       Rose   Apple
4      UK      Lotus  Banana
5      UK  Dandelion   Grape

X_test

  Country   Flower      Fruits
3      UK  Petunia     Berries
1     USA     Lily  Strawberry

X_test2 = X_test.append(
    {'Country': 'SA', 'Flower': 'Rose', 'Fruits': 'Tomato'}, ignore_index=True)
X_test2

  Country   Flower      Fruits
0      UK  Petunia     Berries
1     USA     Lily  Strawberry
2      SA     Rose      Tomato
```

```
from selective_handler_ohe import SelectiveHandlerOHE

she = SelectiveHandlerOHE(raise_error_cols=['Country'])
she.fit(X_train)

she.transform(X_test).toarray()
# array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])


she.transform(X_test2)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ValueError: Found unknown categories SA in column Country during fit
```